# Saving Primefaces layout state

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces, savestate

I understand that Primefaces Layout and Dashboard have state which can be saved.

Could someone help me with snippet code (or some tutorial / how to ) site on how to save Primefaces layout (fullpage) into some persistent database or file.

In this case, I want to enable user to save their own preferences regarding size of the layoutUnit, which layoutUnit is minimized and closed and such whenever they login.

Thank you

ps: I am using Primefaces 2.2 running on Tomcat - essentially the same configuration as downloadable showcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just respond to the events and save the state. User manual gives the details.

```
<p:layout closeListener="#{layoutBean.handleClose}" toggleListener="#{layoutBean.handleToggle}" resizeListener="#layoutBean.handleResize}"/>


public void handleClose(CloseEvent event) {
    LayoutUnit closedUnit = event.getComponent(); //now get all the info related to closedUnit
}

public void handleResize(ResizeEvent event) {
    LayoutUnit resizedUnit = event.getComponent(); //now get all the info related to resizedUnit
}

public void handleToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
    LayoutUnit toggledUnit = event.getComponent();  //now get all the info related to toggledUnit 
    Visibility status = event.getVisibility();
}
```

Now the state can be saved in database and to reproduce the saved state, attributes of the layout units can be set as per the state saved earlier.